# Estimate of Incomplete Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, gamma-function

I have found in my advanced analysis book an exercise which asks about finding certain estimate of the Incomplete Gamma function. Concretely, it reads as follows:

> The Incomplete Gamma function $\Gamma(a,x)$ is defined as $\Gamma(a,x)=\int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}$. If $1<a<2$ and $0\leq s \leq 1$, could you find a constant $C$ such that $\Gamma(a,-\ln(s))\leq Cs$?

I am a little lost and I don't know where to start with this exercise. Could someone help me?

Comment: Can you please reference the book and the exercise number for others later benefit? For a start (without answering the question) are you able to say anything about how the Incomplete Gamma function behaves in the region defined by the allowed values of $a$ and $s$.  Are there any poles for instance?

Comment: @JamesArathoon It is not really a book, it is a kind of notes about the subject which my teacher has given us, so I don't have a reference for it. On the other hand, which is your definition of poles?

Comment: Any value for the Incomplete Gamma function using allowed real values of $a$ and $s$ that is undefined or unbounded in a way that makes the proposed inequality undefinable.

Comment: Try playing with a graph:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k2ixwopera

Answer (score 0):

The way that the question is written is making it more difficult. For short let
$$F(a,s)=\Gamma(a,-\log(s))$$
I'll leave it to you to check (exercise!!) that
$$(\partial_sF)(a,s)=(-\log(s))^{a-1}$$
So, in the vicinty of $s=0$, the function looks like a vertical line, that is to say $(\partial_sF)$ is unbounded in the neighborhood of zero. Hence there is no linear upper bound in this region. To nail the point home, let's say we have found some $c$ such that
$$F(a,s)\leq cs\\ \text{when} ~~0\leq s\leq 1$$
Let's pick some small number $s_0>0$. (Of course, we'd prefer to do our analysis at precisely $s_0=0$, but the derivative breaks in that case.) We know that $F(a,s_0)\geq 0$. And, we know that
$$(\partial_sF)(a,s_0)=(-\log(s_0))^{a-1}=|\log(s_0)|^{a-1}$$
And therefore picking $\epsilon$ to be sufficiently small, we can say
$$F(a,s_0+\epsilon)\geq \epsilon|\log(s_0)|^{a-1}$$
If we compare this to our upper bound, which is
$$c(s_0+\epsilon)$$
It is pretty clear no matter how large or small $\epsilon$ is we can always find an $s_0$ such that
$$\epsilon|\log(s_0)|^{a-1}\geq c(s_0+\epsilon)$$
Play with this other [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dk1xkijvim) to reinforce your intuition.

Maybe this idea is a little unclear, but hopefully playing with the graph I've provided here and in the comments will help.